# Why does FloatAsIfIntegral exist?

Tags: scala

What's the purpose behind [`FloatAsIfIntegral`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.math.Numeric%24%24FloatAsIfIntegral) (and similar objects for `Double` and `BigDecimal`)? It seems like it only allows calling `quot` and `rem` on fractional types, which is presumably undesirable.

Comment: Not an answer, but [relevant commit with relevant comment right next to the single probable usage](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/9b54520a8c5a4f130a1fabbb0d0e7a3ec9022f41#diff-18a9a72953023e0267e7e864074951aaR52). Perhaps it can give somebody some cues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there to allow floating point ranges, e.g. `0.1 to 0.7 by 0.2`.  But this is fraught with peril anyway, due to inaccuracies in floating point math, and `quot` doesn't even do what you would think it ought to (it doesn't produce integer values, so it's identical to `div` instead of being distinct!).

Floating point ranges are tentatively scheduled for deprecation.  `FloatAsIfIntegral` may go away too, if f.p. ranges do.

Comment: I hope they do go away, then.